# Would Chrome Browser automatically clear image cache if out of space?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am working on a image viewing tool that loads thousands of large  elements. I am thinking to display them in multiple pages to save loading time. And I set the `<img>` in previous pages to be `display:none`.

But I am not sure if I should intentionally clear the cached `<img>` when there are too many images/pages loaded? Do browser automatically clear the previously loaded `<img>` that is `display:none` if it is reaching the cache limit? If not, what is the best way to clear the cached image in javascript?

Thanks!